# How to use Dask on Databricks

Tags: dask, databricks, dask-distributed, azure-databricks

I want to use Dask on Databricks. It should be possible (I cannot see why not). If I import it, one of two things happens, either I get an `ImportError` but when I install `distributed` to solve this DataBricks just says `Cancelled` without throwing any errors.

Answer (score 8):

There is now a [dask-databricks](https://github.com/dask-contrib/dask-databricks) package from the Dask community which makes running Dask clusters alongside Spark/Photon on multi-node Databricks quick to set up. This way you can run one cluster and then use either framework on the same infrastructure.

You create an init script that installs `dask-databricks` and uses a Dask CLI command to start the Dask cluster components.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Install Dask + Dask Databricks
/databricks/python/bin/pip install --upgrade dask[complete] dask-databricks

# Start Dask cluster components
dask databricks run
```

Then in your Databricks Notebook you can get a [Dask client](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/client.html) object using the `dask_databricks.get_client()` utility.

```py
import dask_databricks

client = dask_databricks.get_client()
```

It also sets up access to the Dask dashboard via the Databricks web proxy.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have heard of anyone using Dask under databricks, but so long as it's just python, it may well be possible.

The default scheduler for Dask is threads, and this is the most likely thing to work. In this case you don't even need to install `distributed`.

For the Cancelled error, it sounds like you are using distributed, and, at a guess, the system is not allowing you to start extra processes (you could test this with the `subprocess` module). To work around, you could do

```
client = dask.distributed.Client(processes=False)
```

Of course, if it is indeed the processes that you need, this would not be great. Also, I have no idea how you might expose the dashboard's port.

Comment: This sadly still didn't work. However, this is starting to appear as a genuine limitation of Databricks itself which is sad because I actually think Dask is the future of distributed computing in python.

Comment: Don't tell Databricks that! :)

Comment: Hi SARose - I'm curious as to WHY you want to use Dask on Databricks? ie. what's the driver here?

Comment: 1. For data-folks (RS, DS, MLEs), Spark errors and interplay between spark <=> ML libraries is just substandard at best 

\n

2. even with Koalas (pandas_on_spark), the underlying code is scala/spark. There are very opaque tasks that the actual user has usually no transparency into for debugging.

Comment: Coiled's page at https://www.coiled.io/blog/spark-vs-dask gives a good explanation of why one might choose Dask over Spark, or vice versa.  For me, my team comes from a heavy Python/C++ background, we have compute graphs similar to the one shown on the Coiled page but much more complex again (very far from Databricks and Spark's more data-centric home turf), we want deep control over what we run, and we value that Dask is open-source and "plays well with others".